# Why do I get a StackOverflowException when I specify the size of an INTEGER array to be 200,000,000?

Tags: arrays, fortran, stack-overflow

200,000,000 is much less than the maximum 32-bit INTEGER, 2,147,483,647.

Comment: The fact that you thought it was related to INT_MAX leads me to believe you aren't clear on what a stack overflow is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: A stack overflow is related to the size of the Stack, not the size of an Int.

Comment: A stack overflow on StackOverflow.  I think Geoffrey is playing with us.  Neat :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A stack overflow happens not when your notation runs out of bits, but when your computer runs out of memory.  A 200M-entry array would need 800Mb of memory.  That is very large to put on the stack.

Comment: It's not a question of size of memory in general, but rather of stack size, which is smaller than total RAM amount. For example, on my Mac OS laptop with 4GB of RAM, default stack size is 8MB.